# Nginx - how to configure IP address? (returns only 127.0.0.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, ip, unicorn

I have a Rails app on Amazon EC2, with using nginx and unicorn.

When I access **request.remote_ip** or **request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']**, the output is always **127.0.0.1**.

Here's my `nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    upstream example.com {
      server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    server{
      listen 80;

      server_name example.com _;
      root /home/deployer/example/public;

      location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
          proxy_pass http://example.com;
          break;
        }
        if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
          return 503;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I've tried to add these lines:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

But unfortunately, the result was still the same - **127.0.0.1**

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other bug?

Comment: Same here! Using tornado web server as upstream. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
proxy_set_header CLIENT_IP $remote_addr;
```

Comment: Are you restarting the server each time you make a change to the config?

Comment: Should be `Client-IP`, not `CLIENT_IP`.